# Error: value cannot be null. parameter name:g in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a problem in the catalog through a collection of sites in the reference http: //sitio_layouts/15/AddCatalogSource.aspx. When giving you access to the site configuration ► Manage connections to the catalog ► Connect to a catalog ► Choose the required catalog and click the Connect button. Drop the following error: Value ****can not be null. Parameter name: g****

I'm getting this error message value cannot be null. parameter name:g when I try to connect product catalog in sharepoint 2013

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check it out 
[Value cannot be null. Parameter name: g](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/0822dffb-204a-4c41-8fc5-229c52c000ca/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-g?forum=mosses)
Procedure

1. Site settings --> Site Actions --> Manage Site Features --> Disable feature SharePoint Server Publishing.

do this on every web site.

2. Site settings --> Site Collection Administration --> Site Collection Features --> Disable SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure.
3. Open SharePoint 2013 Console Administration - PowerShell - and execute 
   Enable-SPFeature -Identity F6924D36-2FA8-4f0b-B16D-06B7250180FA -Url http:// sitecolection
4. Site settings --> Site Actions --> Manage Site Features --> Enable feature SharePoint Server Publishing.
5. Try again Manage catalog connections.

If you have a lot of websites, you can try PowerShell

Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

## Get-SPWeb -site http:// siteCollection -limit ALL | ForEach-Object {Disable-SPFeature Publishing -Url $_.Url -confirm:$false}

## Get-SPWeb -site http:// siteCollection -limit ALL | ForEach-Object {Disable-SPFeature PublishingWeb -Url $_.Url -confirm: $false}

## Get-SPWeb -site http:// siteCollection -limit ALL | ForEach-Object {Enable-SPFeature Publishing -Url $_.Url -confirm:$false}

## Get-SPWeb -site http:// siteCollection -limit ALL | ForEach-Object {Enable-SPFeature PublishingWeb -Url $_.Url -confirm: $false}

Carlos Pérez - Capa
@Capatechsas